# Where can I echo the search SQL for a ?s=words type search?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to debug the Search Everything plugin, which has worked before for me on sites but not working(returns zero results) on a current site.  If I could see what sql was being performed, I could get a better idea of whats wrong.  This is for a normal search box type search of posts and pages, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL is generated in the `get_posts()` function in [wp-includes/query.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.2/wp-includes/query.php#L2177).  If that link doesn't take you to the right spot, search the function for `if ( !empty($q['s']) )`.

Looks like the `posts_search` filter is called immediately after that block, so you could hook into that to dump the generated SQL to a file (if echoing doesn't work).

Comment: actually, around line 2631 of query.php is
$this->posts = $wpdb->get_results($this->request);
where you can echo $this->request which seems to give the ultimate sql for the search.  Thanks, and now i have to figure out why 
AND ( ctax.term_id NOT IN ( 6 )) 
in the sql is making it return nothing. (category 6 is my sliders, they should not be included in search)